# Excel file with multiple sheets from SSRS Reports

Tags: c#, .net, excel, reporting-services, office-interop

Let's say i have 3 byte arrays, each representin a .xls file. How can i combine them into a single xls file with 3 sheets. The SSRS reports are very rich and include charts sp oledb is not an option.

Performance is not important so i could save them to disk if needed, as a last resort i could even use an excel macro (if i knew how to do that). I tried to use microsodt.office.interop.excel but i could only manage to add a new sheet to a file, i couldn't add an existing sheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Paul I am a little confused about your workflow here, where are the byte arrays coming from 3 xls files you are streaming? Where does SSRS fit in?

Comment: The bvyte arays are in memory, i would ideally combine them in memory, but i'm not sure how feasable that is. The byte arrays are coming from programmatically exporting an ssrs report.

Comment: @Paul - it looks like Joey's answer should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need a way to programatically write Byte arrays to a WorkBook.
Here is a method that will write a byte[] as a sheet to a specific WorkBook:

```
public static void WriteToSheet(string targetBookPath, byte[] fileBytes)
{
    try {
        
        object x = Type.Missing;
        
        //Create a temp file to encapsulate Byte array
        string tmpPath = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(IO.Path.GetTempFileName(), ".xls");
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(tmpPath, fileBytes, false);
        
        //Start Excel Application (COM)
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        
        //Open target book
        Excel.Workbook targetBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(targetBookPath, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, 
        x, x, x, x, x);
        
        //Open temp file with Excel Interop
        Excel.Workbook sourceBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(tmpPath, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, 
        x, x, x, x, x);
        
        //Get a reference to the desired sheet 
        Excel.Worksheet sourceSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sourceBook.Worksheets(1);
        
        //Copy the temp sheet into WorkBook specified as "Before" parameter
        Excel.Worksheet targetBefore = (Excel.Worksheet)targetBook.Worksheets(1);
        try {
            sourceSheet.Copy(targetBefore, x);
            
            //Save and Close
            sourceBook.Close(false, x, x);
            targetBook.Close(true, x, x);
            xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
                
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.Fail(ex.ToString);
        }
        finally {
            
            //Release COM objects
            //   Source
            DESTROY(sourceSheet);
            DESTROY(sourceBook);
            
            //   Target
            DESTROY(targetBefore);
            DESTROY(targetBook);
            
            //   App
                
            DESTROY(xlApp);
        }
        
        //Kill the temp file
            
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(tmpPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.Fail(ex.ToString);
    }
}
```

The DESTROY method releases the COM stuff, which is pretty important:

```
public static void DESTROY(object o)
{
    try {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.Fail(ex.ToString);
        ErrorLog.Write(ex.ToString);
    }
    finally {
        o = null;
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, all you would need to do is:

1. Create a new WorkBook
2. Loop through Byte arrays
3. Call WriteToSheet for each Byte array

Comment: This looks good, i'll check it out when i get into the office.

Comment: I edited the code to play a little nicer with COM. You can get some frustrating errors if you don't treat COM with the respect it "deserves". This works for me!

Comment: I'm making progress here, I'm going to need some marshalling on the COM object i think, since i'm unable to delete the tmp file atm.

Comment: Any1 know how to suppress the "Would you like to save xyx.xls" dialog?

Comment: @Paul - There are 2 ways to suppress the Save Changes dialog. First, if you want to save it call Save or SaveAs on the workbook prior to closing. If you don't care to save, set DisplayAlerts = false on the Excel Application object (xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false)

Answer (score 1):

Do the sheets have to be generated as separate reports and then combined?  SoftArtisans OfficeWriter can programmatically combine multiple spreadsheets from byte arrays, but we also have [SSRS integration](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/default.aspx?pageid=250) that would allow you to create multi-sheet reports directly.  Using the OfficeWriter Designer Excel Add-In you could design a report with 3 worksheets right in Excel and publish it to SSRS.

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it:

- Load source workbooks from the byte arrays with SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbookSet().Workbooks.OpenFromMemory(byte[]). Depending on the source of the byte arrays, you might prefer to load directly from a stream with GetWorkbookSet().Workbooks.OpenFromStream(System.IO.Stream stream).
- Create a new destination workbook with Factory.GetWorkbook() or open a template destination workbook with Factory.GetWorkbook(string filename).
- Copy worksheets from each of the source workbooks with SpreadsheetGear.ISheet.CopyAfter or ISheet.CopyBefore.
- Save the destination workbook with IWorkbook.SaveAs(string filename, FileFormat fileFormat), IWorkbook.SaveToMemory(FileFormat fileFormat) or IWorkbook.SaveToStream(System.IO.Stream stream, FileFormat fileFormat).

You can see a number of live ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

There is a "Worksheet with Chart to Multiple Worksheets with Charts" sample which might be somewhat useful on our Excel Reporting Samples page [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC